# VBA If Countifs

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I use the below to only instigate a certain piece of code if there is data,

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "ASM001") > 0 Then
```

However, I need it to work under a CountIfs as well, as some sheets have more than one criteria, such as the example below where it uses BIR001, BIR004, BIR006, ITI001. I need it to continue if there is at least 1 of ANY of them.

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "BIR001", wksdata.Range("D:D"), "BIR004", wksdata.Range("D:D"), "BIR006", wksdata.Range("D:D"), "ITI001") > 0 Then
```

Can you help locate my error?

Comment: What is the error? Do you get an error message or does it simply return results which are not consistent with your expectation. Help us help you...

Comment: Hi David, it was skipping the steps thinking there was no data but there was (it has the most data on the workbook), but it works with an Or function as described in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't thinking there were no data :) The `CountIfs` requires all the conditions to be true. So yes, it makes sense to simply do a series of `CountIf` with an `Or` operator.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realised I should be adding 4 CountIf functions together.

```
If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "BIR001") _
    + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "BIR004") _
    + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "BIR006") _
    + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "ITI001")) > 0 Then
```

Looks a bit messy but does the job!

Answer (score 3):

This would be a good way to make it less messy:

```
Dim count As Integer

With Application.WorksheetFunction
   count = .CountIf(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "BIR001") + _
           .CountIf(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "BIR004") + _
           .CountIf(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "BIR006") + _
           .CountIf(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "ITI001")
End With

If (count > 0) Then
```

Comment: It looks basically the same but introduces more complexity with the  extra Dim, as such I've not test but it looks good!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a chance to play with some square brackets but you shouldn't use the full column references.

```
If CBool([SUMPRODUCT(--(D1:D99999={"BIR001","BIR004","BIR006","ITI001"}))]) Then
```